# DataGridView to select both by row OR column depending on user click

Tags: c#, datagridview, windows-forms-designer

using C# and Windows Forms

I wish to allow my user to select row(s) for exporting from a dataGridView; however, I also wish to allow them to sort and filter by columns.  Is there a best practice for doing this?  The reason I ask is that it seems to be that you can do one or the other, but not both without intercepting the mouse click and then setting up a method to change the SelectionMode (from RowHeaderSelect to ColumnHeaderSelect).  Is that really the only way to handle this?

Thank you,
Brian.